# how to open parent window tab from javascript popup

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, popup

I have two pages, let's say

1. adminpage.jsp
2. popupadmincatgeory.jsp(which is a popup window)

On adminpage.jsp i am using below script(which in turn opens popupadmincatgeory.jsp),  on a button as shown below:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function newPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(
      url,'winname','height=370,width=680,left=400,top=100,directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,loc       ation=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
    }
   </script>


    <body>
    <div class="element">
<input type="button" class="red"  value="Add category here"      onclick="JavaScript:newPopup('popupadmincategory.jsp');"/>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Now in my popupadmincatgeory.jsp page ,i use below script:

```
  <script>
    function go(subcat) 
       { 

var sel = document.getElementById('menuc');
    var sv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
var selcat = document.getElementById('menu');
    var svcat = selcat.options[selcat.selectedIndex].value;
var selmaincat = document.getElementById('main');
    var svmaincat = selmaincat.options[selmaincat.selectedIndex].value;


    window.open('adminpage.jsp?a='+sv+'&subcat='+svcat+'&maincat='+svmaincat+'');
     window.close("popupcategory.jsp");

       } 

       </script>
```

which in simple words opens another page name as adminpage.jsp, as it can be seen here 
             window.open('adminpage.jsp?a='+sv+'&subcat='+svcat+'&maincat='+svmaincat+'');
in the above script.

Now what i need to know is when user trigger the mentioned script on popupadmincatgeory.jsp page, he must be able to view the next page on same parent window (which is adminpage.jsp).

Right now new tab opens. I know "_parent" parameter allows this on windows.open() , but this is not working at all. Can anyone suggest me any solution based on this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**window.opener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener) , try something like this from within your popup window:

`window.opener.location.href = 'adminpage.jsp?blabla';`